# Meteor.js three-way-databinding without Angular.js

Tags: meteor, synchronization, meteor-blaze

I need to sync some forms with the MongoDB after the user has changed some data and I´m looking for a good solution with as less boilerplate as possible.

I´ve once accomplished that by using Meteor + Angular.js in a pretty straight-forwarded way, but I don´t want to use Angular anymore and currently I´m just fine with Meteor and Blaze and I want to stick with it.

What is a proper way to manage three-way databinding in Meteor.js (syncing input fields with my database on server) ?

Comment: Don't think I've seen 3-way done anywhere, but there are two good packages that extend Blaze with bindings: 

https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/blaze-components

and

https://atmospherejs.com/manuel/viewmodel

Comment: This term comes from the official angular-meteor doku https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/3-way-data-binding